# Why would there be a delay in SCSS compiling?

Tags: sass

I'm using SASS/SCSS as a preprocessor to compile my .scss files on Windows 7, and recently I've noticed that there is a delay of about 15 or 20 seconds between when I save my files and when I get my "Changes detected..." in my command line.  In the past I got it instantaneously but now I get that delay.  Why would this be the case?  Does it depend on the size of the .scss file?  (The one I'm working with is ~550 lines).

Comment: Is that with Compass or another app that's doing the polling for changes?

Comment: Nope.  Just straight up SASS.  No Compass or anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sass change watch interval, to be compile more often](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24350024/sass-change-watch-interval-to-be-compile-more-often)

Answer (score -1):

It can be related to the version of the SASS that you are using. There are few reports of this issue. (though those are pretty old)

On the other hand people are also experiencing slower compile speeds as their projects get bigger due to it being based on ruby. So maybe you could check this article out http://benfrain.com/lightning-fast-sass-compiling-with-libsass-node-sass-and-grunt-sass/

I have been using it with codekit for a while and had no such problems so far (hope it stays that way :). 
Since you are on Windows, a good alternative to codekit is prepros. Those are not free apps, so maybe you could just try using compass with sass - you can set it up in a minute and it just might solve your issue- its worth trying.
You could also try using grunt - check this out https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass