# Sass change watch interval, to be compile more often

Tags: css, sass

I'm using sass to compile scss to css.

After each save it take a bout 15-20 seconds until it compile to scss file to css so I need to refresh few times to see the expected results.  Is there a way to tell Sass to check for changes more often ?

This is the command I use:

```
sass --watch sass --watch app/scss/main/:app/css/
```

I am using Sass 3.3.8 (Maptastic Maple)

Please note that the scss are very short, I just started the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a performance issue in Sass 3.3. See the [related issue on Github](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1019).

Comment: so what should we do, should we wait for new release?

Comment: If your project is as small as you claim it is, then I recommend passing it along to the maintainers of Sass so they have additional test cases to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Sass is ruby based and therefore quite slow, nothing you can do about that. With that said, 15-20 seconds sounds way too slow.

You could try [libsass](https://github.com/sass/libsass/releases/tag/v2.0) instead, which is much faster.

Comment: Not sure how sass2scss is is going to help here, the project says it's just for converting the indented SASS syntax to the more popular SCSS syntax (which the Sass commandline tool can already do).  Furthermore, libsass is not the same thing as Sass.  It tends to lag behind the official Ruby Sass in terms of features and often times generates the incorrect output.

Comment: Still think libsass is a good alternative, but you're right about sass2scss not being very relevant to this question...